# How do I send only one message if the second is black, but send two messages if I fill up both variables?

Tags: javascript, html

I am adding paragraph tags in a div according to the messages I inputted in the buttons. One of the buttons (HUNT) contains two messages, while the second button (SELL) contains only one. The issue I'm having is that whether the second message is blank or not, I always have an "undefined" message show up.

Here is my code:

```js
function addLog(logBefore, logAfter) {
  var par = document.createElement("p");
  var node1 = document.createTextNode(logBefore);
  var node2 = document.createTextNode(logBefore);
  par.appendChild(node1);

  var element = document.getElementById("logs");
  // Here you can also use element.childNodes.length
  const count = document.getElementById("logs").getElementsByTagName("p").length;
  if (count >= 8) {
    element.removeChild(element.childNodes[0]);
  }
  element.appendChild(par);

  if (node2 != '') {
    setTimeout(function addLog(logBefore, logAfter) {
      var par = document.createElement("p");
      var node2 = document.createTextNode(logAfter);
      par.appendChild(node2);

      var element = document.getElementById("logs");
      // Here you can also use element.childNodes.length
      const count = document.getElementById("logs").getElementsByTagName("p").length;
      if (count >= 8) {
        element.removeChild(element.childNodes[0]);
      }
      element.appendChild(par);
    }, 1000);
  };
};


var credits = 0;
var clickPower = 1;

function addCred() {
  credits = credits + clickPower;
  document.getElementById('credits').innerHTML = credits + " Skatts";
};
```

```css
#logs {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

#logs p {
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="credits"></div>
<button onclick="addLog('Hunt begun', 'Hunt successful! You now have ' + credits + ' Skatts'); addCred();">HUNT</button>
<br>
<button onclick="addLog('Resources sold', '')">SELL</button>
<div id="logs"></div>
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

I got bit confused about your code and what it soupes to do but i belive:

- You do not need to to call your timeout function like this:

  ```
  setTimeout(function addLog(logBefore, logAfter) {
  ```
- Why even call it again `addLog` same as parent?? And you do not need to pass values in it as it is nested function that can use your parent values of `logBefore` an `logAfter`, so just do:

  `setTimeout(function () {`

Now when you console log values inside timeout you will see values passed and `nod2` will be populated.

```js
function addLog(logBefore, logAfter) {
  var par = document.createElement("p");
  var node1 = document.createTextNode(logBefore);
  var node2 = document.createTextNode(logBefore);
  par.appendChild(node1);

  
  var element = document.getElementById("logs");
  // Here you can also use element.childNodes.length
  const count = document.getElementById("logs").getElementsByTagName("p").length;
  if (count >= 8) {
    element.removeChild(element.childNodes[0]);
  }
  element.appendChild(par);

  if (node2 != '') {
    setTimeout(function () {
    
      console.log(logBefore)
      console.log(logAfter)
      
      var par = document.createElement("p");
      var node2 = document.createTextNode(logAfter);
      par.appendChild(node2);


      var element = document.getElementById("logs");
      // Here you can also use element.childNodes.length
      const count = document.getElementById("logs").getElementsByTagName("p").length;
      if (count >= 8) {
        element.removeChild(element.childNodes[0]);
      }
      element.appendChild(par);
    }, 1000);
  };
};


var credits = 0;
var clickPower = 1;

function addCred() {
  credits = credits + clickPower;
  document.getElementById('credits').innerHTML = credits + " Skatts";
};
```

```css
#logs {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

#logs p {
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="credits"></div>
<button onclick="addLog('Hunt begun', 'Hunt successful! You now have ' + credits + ' Skatts'); addCred();">HUNT</button>
<br>
<button onclick="addLog('Resources sold', '')">SELL</button>
<div id="logs"></div>
```